# CherryPy How to Read Chunked Encoded Request Body

Tags: python, cherrypy, chunked-encoding

I try to get the data off POST body that has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header (doesn't have `Content-Length`). The content-type is `application/octet-stream`.

I tried

```
cherrypy.request.body.read()
```

But it froze and returned 500

I also tried

```
buffer = cherrypy.request.body.read(1024)
```

But doesn't know when to stop reading.
Anyone has suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using.

```
def POST(self):
    f = open('tmp','wb')
    cherrypy.request.rfile.bufsize = 1024 * 1024 * 5  #adjust buffer size here
    while True:
        cherrypy.request.rfile._fetch();              #reading data
        if cherrypy.request.rfile.closed:             #end of stream checking
            break
        buffer = cherrypy.request.rfile.buffer        #your data is here
        cherrypy.request.rfile.buffer = ""            #clearing buffer
        f.write(buffer)                               #consume it

    f.close()
    return "done"
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution :)